# How do I specify a default value when the value is "null" in a spark dataframe?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame like the picture below.

[image]

In the case of "null" among the values of the "item_param" column, I want to replace the string'test'.
How can I do it?

```
df = sv_df.withColumn("srv_name", col('col.srv_name'))\
      .withColumn("srv_serial", col('col.srv_serial'))\
      .withColumn("col2",explode('col.groups'))\
      .withColumn("groups_id", col('col2.group_id'))\
      .withColumn("col3", explode('col2.items'))\
      .withColumn("item_id", col('col3.item_id'))\
      .withColumn("item_param", from_json(col("col3.item_param"), MapType(StringType(), StringType())) ) \
      .withColumn("item_param", map_values(col("item_param"))[0])\
      .withColumn("item_time", col('col3.item_time'))\
      .withColumn("item_time", from_unixtime( col('col3.item_time')/10000000 - 11644473600))\
      .withColumn("item_value",col('col3.item_value'))\
      .drop("servers","col","col2", "col3")
df.show(truncate=False)
df.printSchema()
```

[image]

Comment: Hey KIMJAEMIN, I was wondering which solution you ended up using and which reasons drove your decision?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#coalesce):

```
.withColumn("item_param", coalesce(col("item_param"), lit("someDefaultValue"))
```

It will apply the first column/expression which is not null

Comment: Thanks, I have found a way to fillna.
But, Your proposition is works find!!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `fillna`, which allows you to replace the null values in all columns, a subset of columns, or each column individually. [[Docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna)]

```
# All values
df = df.fillna(0)

# Subset of columns
df = df.fillna(0, subset=['a', 'b'])

# Per selected column
df = df.fillna( { 'a':0, 'b':-1 } )
```

In you case it would be:

```
df  = df.fillna( {'item_param': 'test'} )
```

Comment: Thanks bro.
Is it collect to do this(import)?
from pyspark.sql.functions import fillna

Comment: You do not need any imports. You can do that directly on the dataframe in question.